# How to add VBA Data Validation from List without error?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with adding data validation list to the New Workbook that I have selected. Firstly I am creating new wb with Array function, than I want to add data validation to C3 Cell in Ukraine worksheet. List to data validation is in SLOWNIK'!$Q$5:$Q$50. I get error 1004. I would be grateful for help.

```
Sheets(Array("Ukraine", "SLOWNIK")).Copy
   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
   Sheets("Ukraine").Activate
   Range("C3").Select
   With Selection.Validation
   .Delete
   .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
   Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="='SLOWNIK'!$Q$5:$Q$50"
   .IgnoreBlank = True
       .InCellDropdown = True
       .InputTitle = ""
       .ErrorTitle = ""
       .InputMessage = ""
       .ErrorMessage = ""
       .ShowInput = True
       .ShowError = True
   End With
```

I got error 1004 on line

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
   Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="='SLOWNIK'!$Q$5:$Q$50"
```

Comment: Change `With Selection.Validation` to `With Sheets("Ukraine").Range("C3").Validation`.

Comment: Unfortunately the error is not there, I have changed it. I have edited the post also, u can see where is the error

Comment: You are using Operator:=xlBetween.  According the Microsoft docs you must provide two formulas https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlformatconditionoperator

Comment: checked, also doesn't work without it :(

Comment: replace the two lines where you get the error with simple this one: .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="1,2,3" does it work?

Comment: still not working :( looks like .Add Type:=xlValidateList is not working properly

Comment: Is the sheet maybe protected? Then error 1004 is returned